# Command prompt text log

Tags: java, parsing, maven, command-prompt

I am typing a command for 'mvn -U clean install' on command prompt, which runs for some time and then informs whether 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL' or 'BUILD FAILED' on command prompt only.

I want to implement something which will keep on parsing the text as it appears on the command prompt,so that when the text matches 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL' or 'BUILD FAILED', it will pop-out relevant message (so as to avoid keep on opening command prompt in-between to check whether Build has finished or it has failed in between).

So, my Q is: How can this be done? Where can I find the log for text generated on command prompt, which I can parse? Or I can parse it directly on command prompt as it generates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using batch. You run the output of the program into a file and then run your application to read the file. Here is an example:

```
@echo off
buildCommand >> output.txt
java yourParserProgram output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to start the `mvn` command from your java program and redirect its output to either a stream or a file that you can read at your convenience

Answer (score 0):

You have many different options there. For example, you could open the command prompt via the Java Process and then scan and parse the output in Java using Scanner.. !?

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start command", null, new File(someFilename));
```

You got the idea, now you could open and parse the output file..

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do

```
mvn -U clean install ; xmessage 'Maven done'
```

as a simple notification, then scroll back to see the results. To get fancy, something like

```
mvn -U clean install | tee /some/convenient/log.txt
tail -n 10 /some/convenient/log.txt | \
   grep 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL' && xmessage 'Maven happy' || xmessage 'Maven sad'
```

There are lots of prettier replacements for `xmessage`, as well, but it does get the job done, most of the time.

If you're on a Windows machine, one cheap and dirty way to get a notification that the program finished is just to queue up a `start` of a sound file or similar.

```
mvn -U clean install
start.exe C:/Users/Somebody/Documents/Foo.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why god invented shells and scripting languages ...

Comment: I'm sure it's not God who invented Bash :))

Comment: Did I say God?  I said god :))

Answer (score 0):

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Execute_a_system_command#Java

I believe you can use this for a non-system command as well.